# Mongo - Find all duplicate docs based on criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, reactive-mongo-java

I have following document

```
{
  "url": "/some/listing/url",
  "title": "HOTELS WITH RIVER VIEW IN SALZBURG",
  "pageType": "LISTING_PAGE",
  "pageMetaData": {
    "$placeId": 123,
    "hotels" : "1,2,3",
    "priority": 1
  }
},
{
  "url": "/some/listing/url",
  "title": "HOTELS FOR FAMILY IN SALZBURG",
  "pageType": "LISTING_PAGE",
  "pageMetaData": {
    "$placeId": 123,
    "hotels" : "1,2",
    "priority": 2
  }
},
{
  "url": "/some/listing/url",
  "title": "HOTELS in AUSTRIA",
  "pageType": "LISTING_PAGE",
  "pageMetaData": {
    "$placeId": 1,
    "hotels" : "1,2,3",
    "priority": 1
  }
},
{
  "url": "/some/listing/url",
  "title": "HOTELS with MOUNTAIN VIEW IN SALZBURG",
  "pageType": "LISTING_PAGE",
  "pageMetaData": {
    "$placeId": 123,
    "hotels" : "1,2,3",
    "priority": 2
  }
},
{
  "url": "/some/listing/url",
  "title": "HOTELS WITH RIVER VIEW IN HALLSTATT",
  "pageType": "LISTING_PAGE",
  "pageMetaData": {
    "$placeId": 34,
    "hotels" : "5,6",
    "priority": 1
  },
  {
  "url": "/some/listing/url",
  "title": "HOTELS FOR FAMILY IN HALLSTATT",
  "pageType": "LISTING_PAGE",
  "pageMetaData": {
    "$placeId": 34,
    "hotels" : "5,6",
    "priority": 2
  },
  {
  "url": "/some/external/url",
  "title": "HOTELS FOR FAMILY IN HALLSTATT",
  "pageType": "EXTERNAL_PAGE",
  "pageMetaData": {
    "$placeId": 34,
    "hotels" : "5,6",
    "priority": 3
  }
}
```

//just a note: hotels is string and already sorted, so if two pages have same set of hotels it will be same string

I am trying to find all the docs which are duplicate for place and sort it based on priority for a page type

For example for Listing_page type the result would based on priority ascending

```
"HOTELS WITH RIVER VIEW IN SALZBURG"  //has prio 1 and has duplicate hotels
"HOTELS WITH RIVER VIEW IN HALLSTAT" //has prio 1 and has duplicate hotels
"HOTELS with MOUNTAIN VIEW IN SALZBURG" //has prio 2 and has duplicate hotels
"HOTELS WITH FAMILY IN HALLSTAT" //has prio 2 and has duplicate hotels
```

since hotels in these places are duplicate of each other. Note even if austria as same hotel, but since it has different place is not considered duplicate

I know how to create a sql query where I could use "not exists" and get the duplicates. But I see that mongo does not have something like not exists. Also I dont want to do group by, as it will lose the pages and I want all pages with duplicate hotels sorted on priority